# C# ASP.NET (VS 2008) DB ignores INSERT if it contains Hebrew characters

Tags: database, visual-studio-2008, encode

Currently I'm working on a project for school, and I can't solve this.

I have a form, and if you insert to it English characters, it works fine and the info is inserted into the DB, but if I insert Hebrew characters (@form), nothing happens.

Now, to clarify, I have tested 100%, that even when I insert Hebrew characters, it gets into the 'if' block which contains the sql insert.

The whole project is managed with Visual Studio Web Developer 2008.

If I manually insert hebrew written values, the DB is able to store them, and output, but when trying to update those cells (@form), all the characters in Hebrew become question marks.

Can anyone help me? I would really appreciate it.

Thanks, Guy

EDIT:

Here is my insertion query: (Errors is a `List<string>`, MyAdoHelper.cs comes next)

```
if (Errors.Count == 0)
{
      string Add_Member = "INSERT INTO members (name, password, email, gender, registration_date) VALUES ('" + Nickname + "', '" + Password + "', '" + Email + "', '" + Gender + "', '" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "')";

      MyAdoHelper.DoQuery(GlobalVar.DatabaseName, Add_Member);

      Errors.Add(GlobalVar.GlobalStatus["Register_Success"]);
}
```

MyAdoHelper.cs:

```
public class MyAdoHelper
{
    public MyAdoHelper()
    {
    }

    public static SqlConnection ConnectToDb(string fileName)
    {
        string path = @"C:\Users\Guy\Desktop\Project\App_Data\";
        path += fileName;
        string connString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" +
                             path +
                             ";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        return conn;
    }

    public static void DoQuery(string fileName, string sql)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = ConnectToDb(fileName);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        com.Dispose();
        conn.Close();
    }

    public static int RowsAffected(string fileName, string sql)       
    {
        SqlConnection conn = ConnectToDb(fileName);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        int rowsA = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        return rowsA;
    }

    public static bool IsExist(string fileName, string sql)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = ConnectToDb(fileName);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        SqlDataReader data = com.ExecuteReader();
        bool found;
        found = (bool)data.Read();

        conn.Close();
        return found;
    }

    public static DataTable ExecuteDataTable(string fileName, string sql)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = ConnectToDb(fileName);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter tableAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        tableAdapter.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }

    public static void ExecuteNonQuery(string fileName, string sql)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = ConnectToDb(fileName);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }

    public static int CountTableRows(string TableName)
    {
        SqlConnection Conn = MyAdoHelper.ConnectToDb(GlobalVar.DatabaseName);
        Conn.Open();
        string TotalRows = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + TableName;
        SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand(TotalRows, Conn);
        return (int)Cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a code sample?  It's a bit hard to troubleshoot without the code.  It could be something as simple as not using parameterized queries, and unexpected characters causing conflict (unintentional sql injection, for example), so it'd be nice to rule that and other simple things out.

Comment: if it is SQL database, is it set to work with Hebrew code-page?

Comment: If you insert Hebrew values manually it works fine, and you can also display them, but when I update them through a form, it goes ???, or nothing is sent to the DB. Displaying Hebrew on the site works too. There is a problem with sending it to the DB, like it doesn't accept the characters, and ignores my request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use microsoft sql server, try something like this.

```
INSERT INTO tabelle (Spalte) VALUES (N'äüö');
```

And make also sure, that you use `nvarchar`

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I do use nvarchar, what is the (Splate) doing?

Comment: I have tried your solution, but it still doesn't insert the hebrew values.

Comment: It was only a example. If you insert a value use **N**'value'. The **N** will help you ;)

Comment: Haha, just translated that, now I get it :) I will try now

Answer (score 0):

i thinks ,you used the nvarchars for hebrew-characters field in your DB...

Comment: Yep, is that what causing the problem? (nvarchar(50))