# Unicode shows up incorrectly on Linq-To-Sql

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, unicode, linq-to-sql

My `ASP.NET` website has a `Linq-To-Sql` database connected with a connection string to an SQL 2008 DB.
Locally, when using an `MDF` file, everything worked fine. I had a "loader" method, looping though files (only once, via admin panel), parsing them and adding to the database. They contain Unicode Hebrew text. I had done this locally. Then, my local website would print out the correct Unicode Hebrew characters to the HTML document. *My whole website is in Hebrew.*

With the connection string provided by my shared hosting provider, dumping the SQL DB (without data!) to an `sql`, executing on server & loading it up from the files, I start seeing question marks (???) instead of Hebrew characters (the website itself, which is in Hebrew shows up correctly). The SQL database has `text` type fields.

The more funny thing is, that it has been working for some time correctly before showing up question marks (!).

How can I make the Hebrew characters show up correctly? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) data type in SQL server represents:

> Variable-length **non-Unicode** data in the code page of the server and with a maximum string length of 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647). *(emphasis mine)*

So, because GoDaddy has a different code page on the server than you do, the unicode chars are getting mangled. `text` was never meant to contain unicode.
You need to use [`nvarchar(max)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx) instead.

As DJ Kraze correctly noted, prefixing your strings with [**N**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239530/en-us) might also be necessary *(I thought it might help to add the explanation).* But since you are using LINQ to SQL, that's not the problem in your case (good catch @Jon Hanna, I missed that tag).

Comment: If you have to update an existing database, you might find `ntext` an easier conversion than `nvarchar(max)`, though do try codesparkle's suggestion first as it's better in a lot of ways. Avoid text, varchar and char for real-world text for humans (the latter two can work okay for codes like airport codes, country codes, and other things mean for computers more than people). They only exist because they need to offer compatibility with stuff from the 1980s.

Comment: Thank you very much. After this modification, it is working (though I still don't understand why it did work locally).

Comment: you're welcome. I'm assuming that your operating system is configured to use the Hebrew code page, thus the text was saved correctly (not as Unicode). But the GoDaddy servers would be configured to use an ANSI code page (for instance, [`Windows-1252`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)).

Answer (score -1):

here is a good example / explanation that might help

You can solve the problem with N at the beginning of string like below it's an example of how to use "N"

```
 string Status_Update = "UPDATE global_status SET  title = '" +
 Title + "', info =N'" + Info + "'  WHERE id = '" +
 Request.Form["Some_Key"] + "'";
```

also make sure to try nvarchar or unicode

Comment: They're using linq-to-sql. This will be done for them with the n-* datatypes already.

Comment: Please at least [link to the original](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10262656/1106367) if you are copying 90% of the answer.